# to_timestamp adding +5:30 to my STRING timestamp

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have created a following function using Spark Dataset, which converts STRING based "dates (yyyy-mm-dd)"/"timestamps" to TIMESTAMP datatype -

```
/**
 * Converts string date/datetime to Timestamp datatype.
 *
 * @param df            dataframe
 * @param timestampCols timestamp columns
 * @return {@link Dataset<Row>} modified dataframe
 */
public static Dataset<Row> convertTimestampColumns(Dataset<Row> df, List<String> timestampCols) {
    Dataset<Row> modifiedDf = df;
    for (String columnName : df.columns()) {
        if (timestampCols.contains(columnName)) {
            modifiedDf = modifiedDf.withColumn(columnName,
                    to_timestamp(df.col(columnName)));
        }
    }
    modifiedDf.show();
    return modifiedDf;
}
```

But when I am testing it -

```
@Test
    public void testConvertTimestampColumns() {
        SharedJavaSparkContext javaSparkContext = new SharedJavaSparkContext();
        Dataset<Row> df;
        try (SparkSession spark = new SparkSession(javaSparkContext.sc())) {
            List<Row> data = Arrays.asList(
                    RowFactory.create(1, "2022-01-01", "2019-03-26T20:28:32.000Z")
            );

            List<StructField> fields = Arrays.asList(
                    DataTypes.createStructField("id", DataTypes.IntegerType, true),
                    DataTypes.createStructField("date_col1", DataTypes.StringType, true),
                    DataTypes.createStructField("date_col2", DataTypes.StringType, true)
            );

            StructType schema = DataTypes.createStructType(fields);
            df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema);
        }

        List<String> timestampCols = Arrays.asList("date_col1", "date_col2");

        // Convert timestampCols to TimestampType
        Dataset<Row> resultDF = FactSalesforceCRMETLUtils.convertTimestampColumns(df, timestampCols);

        // Check the schema and converted values
        Assert.assertEquals(DataTypes.TimestampType, resultDF.schema().fields()[1].dataType());
        Assert.assertEquals(DataTypes.TimestampType, resultDF.schema().fields()[2].dataType());
        Assert.assertEquals("2022-01-01 00:00:00.0", resultDF.first().getAs("date_col1").toString());
        Assert.assertEquals("2019-03-26 20:28:32.0", resultDF.first().getAs("date_col2").toString());
    }
```

My last assert is failing because the function is adding +5:30 to the provided STRING timestamp.

I tried other functions like `to_utc_timestamp` *,* `from_utc_timestamp` provided by Spark but nothing helps.

Do I need to create a UDF to solve this? Or is there something internal from Spark that can solve my need?

Comment: Looks like a timezone issue to me. Is your Spark cluster running in a geographical region with a timezone that is 5,5 hours ahead of UTC?

Comment: Yes, I am from India. It's +5:30 from UTC timezone. I thought so, my clusters are in UTC timezone so it should be fine in DEV/QA, but still can't I force a timezone in the params?

Comment: Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63800874/2129801). This should guide you into the correct direction. (The question is about PySpark, but the idea is the same.)